# Update AWS RDS SSL/TLS Certificate from rds-ca-2015 to rds-ca-2019

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

We Have recently updated the SSL for AWS rds from rds-ca-2015 to rds-ca-2019. Now application working and connected with SSL, but we couldn't able confirm the rds now using rds-ca-2019. Anyone, please update, how to confirm AWS RDS SSL using rds-ca-2019? Below the steps, we followed to renew the SSL.

```
1. Download the PEM file from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

2. mysql -h testdb.xxxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem  --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY -u username -p

3. In AWs console, In the Network & Security section, changed from rds-ca-2015 to rds-ca-2019, Rebooted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can find an answer here by checking which Mysql user is using ssl for connection and how to check ca in rds and steps to update ca 2019 in rds.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ssl-certificate-rotation-mysql.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html

Comment: try to provide a hint or short note about your answer. so that it helps others. link wont.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check the certificate authority currently used by your RDS instance, you can follow the steps below.

1. Navigate to the RDS service from the AWS console.
2. Click on **Databases** in the navigation panel on the left side.
3. Click on the RDS instance that you need to check.
4. The **Certificate authority** listed in the **Connectivity & security** tab shows the certificate authority currently used by the RDS instance.

Comment: Hi Nilushan, Thanks for your response, In AWS GUI we have checked its showing 2019-ca, Can you please tell me how to check in MySQL command line. Thanks in advance.